# Character offset with grep

Tags: bash, grep

When I run this on my bash terminal:

```
grep -ob "amilase" <<< "α-amilase"
```

I get this:

```
3:amilase
```

Let's define **byte offset** as the number of bytes before the matching word and **character offset** as the number of user-visible characters before the matching word.

Above, the 3 corresponds to the **byte offset** of the matching word. α is an unicode character that occupies 2 bytes, that's why we get the 3.

But how can I get the **character offset**, that in this case would be 2? Why 2? If you look at the screen and count how many visible symbols exist before the matching word, you would count 2.

I'm looking for a solution that behaves like grep -o, that is, if there is more than one match per line, they all are reported.

Comment: Why do you expect to get 2?

Comment: Because there are 2 characters (α-) before "amilase", so 2 would be the character offset? Or am I confused about the concept of "character"?

Comment: You already answered yourself; "α" occupies 2 bytes.

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't explain myself well. Question edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can whip up your own poor-man's grep!

Put this in a script named, say, `mygrep` :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Takes extended regex as first argument
# Text to match received on standard in
if
  [[ $# != 1 ]]
then
 echo "This script takes one argument as input"
 exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r LINE
do
  while true
  do
    [[ "$LINE" =~ ^(.*)($1)(.*)$ ]] || break
    echo "${#BASH_REMATCH[1]}:$1"
    LINE="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  done | tac
done
```

Then simply replace `grep` in your command :

```
mygrep "amilase" <<< "α-amilase"
```

The script loops over all lines of input, matches each one with the regex received as an argument (it can be a simple string, but you have the full power of regular expressions to your fingertips if needed).  I have updated my answer to allow for multiple matches on a single line.  The `| tac` is used to reverse the order of lines, as the greedy matching matches the last occurrence on each line first : if you do not mind the matches appearing in reverse, just remove `| tac`.

I am not sure the output is what you would want, and you can customize it easily.

Please note the `=~` operator does pattern matching (egrep syntax), and BASH_REMATCH is an array used to access (starting at index 1) the sub-expressions inside parentheses.

Comment: My script does extract the offset "${#BASH_REMATCH[1]}" and displays it in the format of the OP, why did you down-vote me?  The offset is the length of the prefix preceding the text matching the user-supplied argument.  Using this script on the OP input yields 2:amilase as requested, I tested it.

Comment: @Inian You forgot to supply "amilase" as the first argument.  My script does not perform any error checking, I will improve that.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so it might match more than expected if the pattern in `$1` could match multiple substrings in the input. `bash` will also only find one match, while `grep -o` will report all the matches.

Comment: The code above will report one match per line of input, which may or may not be what the OP is looking for.  It is true that with the greedy ".*", the script will report the last occurrence.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that behaves like grep -o, that is, if there is more than one match per line, they all are reported. :)

Comment: Try my updated solution, and see comments for the order of matches

Comment: @Fred: thanks for the cool (almost forkless) implementation! I would just print `"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` instead of `$1` as the latter can also be a regular expression (and so no reflecting the actually found string).

Answer (score 1):

if you want a 0-based index of match, you can try this with awk:

```
awk '{print index($0,"amil")-1}'<<< "α-amilase"    
2

awk '{print index($0,"amil")-1}'<<< "fooamilα-whatever"        
3
```

If no match found, it prints `-1`

Comment: This also only reports one match, while `grep -o` will report multiple matches in the same line.

Comment: Edited question, added this: "I'm looking for a solution that behaves like grep -o, that is, if there is more than one match per line, they all are reported."

Comment: If `index()` could be converted into `match()` and a loop, this could work, I think.